# Get select html5 variable into a php and use it in a mysql query as limit?

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I have a select option on my php file inside a form;

```
    <select name="zxclimit" id="zxclimit"> 
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="280">280</option>
    <option value="260">260</option>
    <option value="220">220</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="180">180</option>
    <option value="160">160</option>
    <option value="120">120</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
```

While on my other separate php file with the query;

```
$limit = intval($_GET['zxclimit']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all Order By Rand() Limit '$limit' ");
```

Every time this query runs, it seems that it won't get the variable $limit in the query. But if I use constant limit like `100` it perfectly runs. Really would like some help from this to know what i'm doing wrong in both codes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `<form method="get">`? Please, extend the code, this little part doesn't look wrong on its own.

Comment: @ROAL i forgot to say i'm using post and i modified the get inside the limit into request as well.

Comment: You have to remove single quotes in query: `LIMIT $limit`

Comment: @fusion3k i tried it but it's still the same.

Comment: It could also be that there is no value set, try using `print_r` on `$_GET` to see the value of `$_GET['zxclimit']`, if this is not filled in you have to supply a default value to the `select` I think

Comment: 1) check if `$limit` is set; 2) check query error ( `mysql_error()` ); 3) switch to `mysqli_` or `pdo`: `mysql_` is **DEAD** (deprecated and removed in php 7)

Comment: Please Use Mysqli for better security.

Comment: i think there's some issue on my script, i'm trying to explore it now and try all your answers. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the form using "get" or "post" method?

You should be able to access it using $_REQUEST variable regardless if it's post or get.

> $_REQUEST - An associative array that by default contains the contents
>   of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

So try:

```
$limit = intval($_REQUEST['zxclimit']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all Order By Rand() Limit '$limit' ");
```

If your form is using post you can do:

```
 $limit = intval($_POST['zxclimit']);
```

Please also do not use mysql_ extension (is deprecated and removed in php 7).
Best to switch to mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: I've seen the latest chrome (49.x.x) sending a *GET* request when no `method` is specified so a form without a method should default to *GET* (in chrome atleast)

Comment: @zachu i did try this, it still won't run. yes i'm using post and i used request for it. though if it's constant numbers for the limit, it works. i wonder why it won't get the values from the select in the separate php.

Comment: Please post results of var_dump($_POST);

Comment: I think there's some issues on my script, so i'll explore it and try everything again. thanks